# How to handle checkout with ngrx/store ngrx/effect

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to angular2 ngrx/store and ngrx/effects.  I have put together an application that I have put items into a store.  I am unable to checkout properly.  My store consists of header information like shipping information along with item information that is an array. like this:

```
export interface State {
    entities:CatalogDetail[];
    cart: Cart;
};
```

my action:

```
export const ActionTypes = {
    CHECKOUT_REQUEST: 'Checkout',
}

export class CheckoutAction implements Action {
    type = ActionTypes.CHECKOUT_REQUEST;

    constructor (public payload:CatalogDetail[]) { }
```

}

I need to create a header record that contains the shipping information from the cart and then create the catalog information once I receive the order number.  I have to use two rest services one for each function.  I am able to create the order.

by doing this:

```
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
    public collections:Observable<CatalogDetail[]>;
    public collectionsCart:Observable<Cart>;

    actions$ = new Subject<Action>();

    errorMessage:string = " ";
    orderNumber:Observable<number>;
    details:CatalogDetail[];
    public final = false;

    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
          private router:Router,
          private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
          private orderService:OrderService) {
        this.collections = store.let(fromRoot.getCollectionEntities);
        this.collectionsCart = store.let(fromRoot.getCollectionCart);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.employee = this.employeeService.getEmployeeInfo('0R5821');
        this.final = false;
    }

    checkout(inCart: Cart) {
        this.final = true;
        console.log("inCheckOutMethod: " + inCart.shipToName);
        this.store.dispatch(new collection.UpdateCartAction(inCart));

        //create the order and return the order number
        this.orderNumber = this.orderService.createOrders(inCart);
        this.store.dispatch(new collection.CheckoutSuccessAction([]));
    }
}
```

the effect I wrote that only works if I have one catalogDetail in the payload:

```
@Injectable()
export class ShopEffects {

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private orderService:OrderService, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { }

   @Effect()
       checkOut$ = this.actions$
          .ofType(cart.ActionTypes.CHECKOUT_REQUEST)
          .map(toPayload)
          .switchMap(payload => this.orderService.createOrderItem(payload, "0R5821", 33439))
         .map(payload => this.store.dispatch(new collectionActions.CheckoutSuccessAction([])));
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the actual problem you are facing. Can you provide more clarity regarding what aspect you are facing problem.

Comment: In your `checkout` function, you are first dispatching an `UpdateCartAction`, then you are using `orderService` to get the order and in the end you are dispatching `CheckoutSuccessAction`. But in your code you haven't provided any information about these.